# using static method as internal method

Tags: python, python-3.x

Apologies if the title is misleading/incorrect, as I am strictly not aware of terminologies.

I have a class, let's call it `Cleaner` and this should have couple of methods in it.
For example:

```py
class Cleaner:
   def __init__(self, df):
       self.df = df

   @staticmethod
   def clean(self, dataframe = None):
       if dataframe is None:
           tmp = self.df
       # do cleaning operation
```

The function `clean` should behave as both staticmethod and internal method. What I mean by that is, I should be able to call it in both of the following ways:

```py
tble = pd.read_csv('./some.csv')

cleaner = Cleaner(tble)

#method 1
cleaner.clean()

#method 2
Cleaner.clean(tble)
```

I will acknowledge that I have very nascent knowledge of OOP concept in python and would like your advise, if this is something doable and how so?

Comment: Don't do that.  It's confusing and not worth the trouble.   By leaving it as a regular method, you can accomplish method 2 via `Cleaner(tble).clean()`.  Is that really so awful?

Comment: I'm going to agree with @TimRoberts that this is a terrible idea.  But in my mind, `Cleaner` is a utility class consisting of nothing but static methods.  And if `Cleaner` is filled with static methods, each describing things you can do on a dataframe, so be it.

Comment: Very good point.  If you want to use a class just as a namespace to contain related utility functions, that's perfectly fine.  But in that case, you don't need to create instances at all.